# How to append ArrayList data into Class Object

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

I am storing data in class object from array List like

```
MyClass[] obj = list.toArray(new myclass[0]);
```

if i want to append ArrayList data into MyClass object. what should i need to do?
i want to do somethink like

```
obj = obj.append(list);
```

Comment: what do you want to say exactly?

Comment: how can i append to class object from arraylist?

Comment: can you elaborate your question and your basic requirement,i will give you any alternative solution.

Comment: you can try getter,setter method to add data to your class

Comment: i have each time array list and just want to append in exit object.

Comment: show your code snippet

Comment: is there any function who will transfer arraylist data into class object without losing previous data of class-object?

Answer (score 1):

The length of an array is immutable in java. This means you can't change the size of an array once you have created it. So if you don't know the final size of the array you can't do what you want using Array.

When you do:

```
MyClass[] obj = list.toArray(new myclass[0]);
```

You are creating an Array with `size=1`. Then you can't add elements.

Using `List` instead of `Array` could be a good solution.

Comment: now i have just two custom class object and want to add both. i mean copy one to another

Comment: Sorry but I don't see what you mean. You have to different kinds of Objects and you want add one of them to the other. Or same Objects?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken `ArrayList` with array.
`ArrayList` is a raw type meaning it needs parameter to instantiate like:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

which creates an empty `ArrayList` which will contain `String`.
You can add `String` by using `arrayList.add("Something");`. Now your array contains 1 element (`String`).

On the other hand assuming `list` is an `ArrayList` `list.toArray()` method will return an array (and does not take any argument). I don't think you want something like this.